# Take User input to select which variable to edit

Tags: java

I'm trying to take user input to select the variable they want to edit.  Say i have 10 variables, I want the user to be able to input "Row 1" and that prompts them to change the value of that variable through another input.  I would post code, but I don't have any to post relating to this because I don't even know how to start.

Edit: I don't want to have something like this:

```
if (input == "row 1") {     
    r1 = scan.nextInt();
}
```

as I'm dealing with a lot of variables and don't want to have to make a statement for ever single one.

Comment: Don't compare Strings with ==. Use .equals() instead.

Comment: Use an array and have the user enter an array index number which would be analogous to a row number. Just remember that an array is zero based range, 0 to length - 1, so they either need to enter 0 through length of array minus one or you will need to modify the entered value if they enter some other range such as 1 to length.

Answer (score 2):

Done in a couple minutes. Just to show you a pattern.

```
public class TestClass {
    private final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(16);
    private final Map<String, RowHolder> holderMap = new HashMap<>(16);

    {
        list.add("LoL 1");
        list.add("LoL 2");
        list.add("LoL 3");
        list.add("LoL 4");
        list.add("LoL 5");

        holderMap.put("Row 1", RowHolder.of(v -> { list.set(0, v); }, s -> list.get(0)));
        holderMap.put("Row 2", RowHolder.of(v -> { list.set(1, v); }, s -> list.get(1)));
        holderMap.put("Row 3", RowHolder.of(v -> { list.set(2, v); }, s -> list.get(2)));
        holderMap.put("Row 4", RowHolder.of(v -> { list.set(3, v); }, s -> list.get(3)));
        holderMap.put("Row 5", RowHolder.of(v -> { list.set(4, v); }, s -> list.get(4)));
    }

    public String getRow(final String row) {
        return holderMap.get(row).function.apply(row);
    }

    public void setRow(
            final String row,
            final String value) {
        holderMap.get(row).consumer.accept(value);
    }

    static class RowHolder {
        final Consumer<String> consumer;
        final Function<String, String> function;

        RowHolder(
                final Consumer<String> consumer,
                final Function<String, String> function) {
            this.consumer = consumer;
            this.function = function;
        }

        static RowHolder of(
                final Consumer<String> consumer,
                final Function<String, String> function) {
            return new RowHolder(consumer, function);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage is basically:

```
final TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
final String rowValue = testClass.getRow("Row 1");
testClass.setRow("Row 1", "LoL LoL");
```